# Access website on one VirtualBox guest OS from another VirtualBox guest OS

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox on a Mac. I have a virtual machine running Linux on which I'm developing  a website. Its hosts file has:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 my-test-site.gyford.com
```

I can then access `http//my-test-site.gyford.com` on my Mac's browser.

But I also have some Windows virtual machines from https://modern.ie/ for browser testing and would like to access the same website from IE in those machines.

I've tried adding

```
127.0.1.1 my-test-site.gyford.com
```

to the Windows machines' host files, but as I expected, it can't find the site.

Is there a way to access the website running on the Linux virtual machine from the Windows virtual machine?

Comment: If the server is the virtual machine then you need to add the virtual machine's local LAN ip address to the hosts file which of course is NOT 127.0.0.1

Comment: Are these guests configured with network interfaces? How are the network interfaces configured? Are they set for NAT, or bridged, or something else?

Comment: @Ramhound - The server is on a virtual machine and the client is on a different virtual machine.

Comment: @Kenster - Both virtual machines are on NAT at the moment, which seems to be default.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the localhost which isnt valid beyond the machine itself

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. Configure your Linux VM: VirtualBox -> Settings -> network -> Bridged adapter. Now, your Linux machine have unique IP. Example: 10.6.204.58
2. In your Windows machine: prompt -> ping 'Linux IP number'. Example: ping 10.6.204.58. If listen, then OK!!!
3. Open Explorer browser and change the address 127.0.0.1 (localhost) to Linux IP. Example: 10.6.204.58/nameApp

Answer (score -1):

127.0.1.1 is a localhost and it will not open the Website built in linux. Please try adding the IP of Website(Public IP/Static IP of that website) and save the hosts file. Then check the workablitiy!

Comment: I don't quite understand... As I understand it the website doesn't have a public IP address - it's just hosted on a virtual machine on my laptop. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Then use the local ip address of the Linux box and adjust it in the hosts file.